# How can I edit a video to correct an incorrect orientation?

Tags: video, auto-rotation

I recorded a video clip on my Samsung Galaxy S4 in the horizontal orientation. If I download it to a computer it plays correctly in a wide aspect ratio and is not rotated.

When I play it on the phone, the phone always rotates it incorrectly.  If I hold the phone in the vertical orientation, the video fills the screen, but is rotated 90 degrees. The bottom of the frame is on the left.

If I rotate the phone 90 degrees CCW to view the video in the correct orientation, the phone rotates the video another 90 degrees.  Now the video is a tiny thumbnail in the middle of the screen - a vertical video showing on a horizontal screen. The bottom of the video is still on the left.

Why is the phone rotating the video incorrectly? Isn't the phone supposed to note the orientation and tag the file when the video is recorded so this problem won't happen? Given that it has it wrong, how do I edit the video to correct the orientation setting?